# Create a column to categorize numerical values in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, categories

I have a dataframe in python called df that includes the BMI of customers as numbers in a column called 'bmi'.  I want to add a new column to the dataframe, called 'bmi_cat' that is the category of BMI based on its numerical value (ie: <18.5 is underweight, 18.5 to 24.9 is healthy, etc.).

This is what I tried, but it didn't work.  It didn't like the use of 'for.'

```
df['bmi_cat'] = for i in df['bmi'] :
                if i < 18.5 :
                    df['bmi_cat'] == 'underweight'
                elif i >= 18.5 and i < 25 :
                    df['bmi_cat'] == 'healthy'
                elif i >= 25 and i < 30 :
                    df['bmi_cat'] == 'overweight'
                else :
                    df['bmi_cat'] == 'obese'
```

I am just learning python...any help you can provide would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a list of conditions and corresponding values to select so you can use [`np.select`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html):

```py
import numpy as np

bmi = df["bmi"]

cond_list = [bmi < 18.5, bmi < 25, bmi < 30, bmi >= 30]
choice_list = ["underweight", "healthy", "overweight", "obese"]

df["bmi_cat"] = np.select(cond_list, choice_list)
```

It checks the conditions in `cond_list` from left to right and whenever it finds a match, looks up in the `choice_list` and assigns that value.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pd.cut`

```
import numpy as np
bins = [-np.inf,18.5, 25, 30, np.inf]
labels = ["underweight","healthy","overweight","obese"]
df['bmi_cat'] = pd.cut(df['bmi'], bins=bins, labels=labels)
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
customers = [
    {"name": "Ken", "bmi": 24},
    {"name": "ben", "bmi": 18.5},
    {"name": "sarah", "bmi": 18.4},
    {"name": "dave", "bmi": 12},
    {"name": "kenneth", "bmi": 18},
    {"name": "dylan", "bmi": 25},
    {"name": "scott", "bmi": 30},
]


for customer in customers:
    if customer["bmi"] < 18.5 :
        customer['bmi_cat'] = 'underweight'
    elif customer["bmi"] < 25 :
        customer['bmi_cat'] = 'healthy'
    elif customer["bmi"] < 30 :
        customer['bmi_cat'] = 'overweight'
    else :
        customer['bmi_cat'] = 'obese'

    print("Customer {name} has BMI {bmi} category {bmi_cat}".format(
        name=customer["name"], 
        bmi=customer["bmi"],
        bmi_cat=customer["bmi_cat"])
    )
```